# css first letter transformation?

Tags: css, transformation, flip

i'm trying to flip first letter of h1 tag on mouse over, but not work!

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>


h1 {
  color: #FF0000;
}

h1:first-letter:hover {
 
  color: #000;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out 0s;
  
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>RISVOLTO</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

I certainly didn't understand how to do it :(

Comment: try `h1:hover:first-letter`

Comment: transform attribute don't work :(
only color change

Comment: Transform do not work with pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, this is not possible.

However, if you are able to edit the HTML, you could wrap the first letter in another element and transition this.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: #FF0000;
    }
    
    h1 span {
      display: inline-block;
      transition: all 3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    
    h1:hover span {
      color: #000;   
      transform: scaleX(-1);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1><span>R</span>ISVOLTO</h1>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as `transform` is not a property recognised by `:first-letter`.

Only a subset of CSS is applicable to the pseudo-element.

[**More details at MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Answer (score 0):

Not all pseudo-classes can go before pseudo-elements. In this case it should be `h1:hover:first-letter`.
The transform won't work because :first-letter can only be used for:

- font properties
- color properties
- background properties
- margin properties
- padding properties
- border properties
- text-decoration
- vertical-align (only if float is 'none')
- text-transform
- line-height
- float
- clear

You can read more about it at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp)

Comment: thanks to all! i will use a span for the first letter!